# Trigger action on next page with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a form that I cannot edit the markup of directly. 
The form looks likes this:

```
<form action="/nextpage" method="post">
<input type="text">
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Once the form is submitted the user goes to the next page. On the next page I want to display success message. Is this possible with jQuery?

Comment: Add code to the next page which displays the message.  Have you tried anything?  What didn't work?

Comment: @David The next page only needs to show the code when coming from the form page.

Comment: Is it "when coming from this page" or is it "when receiving this form post"?  The two are somewhat different things.  In the former case, you need to add something to this page to include a flag of some sort and add code to the next page to display the message when seeing that flag.  In the latter case, you need to add code to the next page to display the message when seeing the form post.  Either way, the code to display a message is on the next page.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, it depends on what the next page is. Can you control the output of the next page? Also, what language is the backend server written with? This is because you can output javascript code from php or you could look in the url for any identifiers in javascript that could trigger a success message.

Comment: I can control the output. The pages are built in php. If I added something to the URL how could jQuery detect that?